# Trouble with NET/HTTP post data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, net-http

So, if I execute the following command, it works fine:

```
curl -X POST --compressed -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H 'x-api-user: USER_ID' \
  -H 'x-api-key: API_TOKEN' \
  -d '{"text":"from the api!","type":"todo"}' \
  https://habitrpg.com/api/v1/user/task
```

I tried getting HTTParty to work, but their documentation on compressed connections is basically non-existent at my level of understanding. I have tried NET/HTTP and I can establish a connection, but the API keeps giving me errors that my data is wrong (it says I haven't given it a valid type). Here is the code I am using:

```
data = {:text => "from the app dog", :type => "todo"}
uri = URI.parse("https://habitrpg.com/api/v1/user/task")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.set_debug_output($stdout)
http.use_ssl = true
resp = http.post(uri.request_uri, data, {"x-api-user" => USER_ID, "x-api-key" => API_TOKEN})
resp.body
```

I have also tried all of the following for the data:

```
data = {:text => "from the app dog", :type => "todo"}.to_json.to_s
data = "{\"text\":\"from the app dog\",\"type\":\"todo\"}"
data = "'" + "{\"text\":\"from the app dog\",\"type\":\"todo\"}" + "'"
```

And probably three or four other things that I can't identify anymore. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am at a total loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `curl` command has a Content-Type set. None of the Ruby code you posted has that.

I'm guessing the app cannot detect and parse the JSON given to it.

Comment: You have no idea how stupid that makes me feel. I seriously spent 30 minutes messing around with that string.